# Do I have to cite the website I used to draw a circuit?

Tags: copyright, copyright-notice

I need to draw some boolean circuits. If I use a web-app like [https://logic.ly/demo/](https://logic.ly), do I need to cite or refer to them? Or somehow attribute that the icons are not owned by me?

To put it explicitly: If I draw a circuit with such an app and export an image or do a screenshot of that circuit, and I publish this image in a document, is there any other action needed in order for this to be legal?

(something like: image was created using https://logic.ly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EULA for the site you referenced is available at:

[LOGIC.LY EULA](https://logic.ly/help/eula/)

It says:

> Under this End User License Agreement (the "Agreement"), Bowler Hat
> LLC (the "Vendor") grants to the user (the "Licensee") a non-exclusive
> license (the "License") to use Logicly (the "Software").
>
> "Software" includes the executable computer programs and any related
> printed, electronic and online documentation and any other files that
> may accompany the product.
>
> "Authorized User" means a single person running a single copy of the
> Software on a single physical computer.
>
> Title, copyright, intellectual property rights and distribution rights
> of the Software remain exclusively with the Vendor. This Agreement
> constitutes a license for use only and is not in any way a transfer of
> ownership rights to the Software.
>
> The Licensee must limit use of the Software to the number of
> simultaneous Authorized Users as designated in the receipt or invoice
> issued by the Vendor or a third-party authorized by the Vendor.
>
> The Licensee may load and run the Software for purposes of evaluation
> for a period of thirty (30) days from the date of installation. At the
> end of the evalution period, the Licensee must discontinue use of the
> Software or obtain a product key for the Software from the Vendor in
> order to continue use of the Software.
>
> The Licensee may not modify, reverse-engineer, or de-compile the
> Software in any manner through current or future available
> technologies.
>
> If any provision of this Agreement is held to be void, invalid,
> unenforceable or illegal, the other provisions shall continue in full
> force and effect.
>
> The Software is provided "as is", without warranty of any kind,
> express or implied, including but not limited to the warranties of
> merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose and
> non-infringement. In no event shall the Vendor be liable for any
> claim, damages or other liability, whether in an action of contract,
> tort or otherwise, arising from, out of or in connection with the
> Software or the use or other dealings in the Software.

The license does NOT require you to cite or acknowledge them in any way.  So as long as you adhere to the rest of the terms of the license agreement, you can do what you want with the resultant drawings.